# Access to attributes from relationship on ember-data models

Tags: model, controller, ember.js, relationship, ember-data

I'm working on a small application like a Social Network to manage projects. Right now, I'm working on friendship relations on the network. For that I've created a model called 'Person' with the next attributes:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend
(
   {
      name: DS.attr('string'),
      place: DS.attr('string'),
      email: DS.attr('string'),
      password: DS.attr('string'),
      academic: DS.attr('string'),
      professional: DS.hasMany('App.Work'),
      knowledge: DS.attr('string'),
      projects: DS.hasMany('App.Project'),
      friends: DS.hasMany('App.Person')
   }
);
```

Now, I'm trying to get the list of friends of a person in the controller, but I don't know how to access to this. Trying something like `this.get('model').get('friends')` show in the template a string like `<DS.ManyArray:ember358>`. What's the right way to access to this? Should it be done on the Controller, on the Route, should I create an additional View or something like that?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

---

*EDIT*:

I've added exactly what @ArturMalecki said but I'm getting `<DS.ManyArray:ember360>`. This is what I've got:

**Person Controller**

```
App.PersonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
(
  {
    friends: function() 
    {
      return this.get('model').get('friends');
    }.property('model.friends'),
  }
);
```

**Router**

```
App.Router.map
(
  function()
  {
    this.resource('app', { path: '/' }, function ()
    {
      // Additional child routes
      this.route('friends');
      ...
    });
    this.resource('person');
  }
);

App.PersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend
(
  {
    model: function()
    {
      return App.Person.find();
    }
  }
);

App.AppFriendsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
(
  {
    model: function()
    {
      return App.Person.find();
    }
  }
);
```

**Handlebars template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="app/friends">
  <h1>Friends</h1>
  <ul>
    {{#each model itemController="person"}}
      <li>{{name}}, from {{place}}. Him/her friends are <{{friends}}>
    {{else}}
      You've no still friends
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

**Output**

> ### Friends
>
> <*person1*>, from <*place1*>. Him/her friends are <`<DS.ManyArray:ember360>`>
>   <*person2*>, from <*place2*>. Him/her friends are <`<DS.ManyArray:ember361>`>
>   <*person3*>, from <*place3*>. Him/her friends are <`<DS.ManyArray:ember362>`>

By the way, I've been trying to get something working, and it actually works, but I'm sure it's not the optimal solution and probably it's not a good practice either. Certainly is not applicable for every case:

```
friends: function()
{
  var model = this.get('model');

  var friendsList = model.get('friends').mapProperty('name');

  return friendsList;
}.property('model.friends'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your route you need to set up `model`. Lets assumed that you have `PersonRoute` and `PersonController`

```
App.PersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Person.find()
  }
});
```

Then you can access to `friends` property in the controller in this way:

```
App.PersonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  someCustomMethod: function() {
    ...
    this.get('model').get('friends');
    ...
  },
})
```

Remember that you need to add person to the routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
 this.resource("person");
});
```

### Update

Simple example how to use `hasMany` relation in view http://jsfiddle.net/Mwg89/10/

#### HTML

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{#each friend in friends}}
      {{friend.name}}
    {{/each}}
    <hr/>
    {{#each friend in model.friends}}
      {{friend.name}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

#### JS

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    friends: DS.hasMany('App.Person'),
});

App.Person.FIXTURES = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Person1', friends: [2,3] },
    { id: 2, name: 'FriendPerson1' },
    { id: 3, name: 'FreindPerson2' }

];

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Person.find(1);
    }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    friends: function() {
        return this.get('model').get('friends');
    }.property('model.friends')
})
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestiong but I'm getting the same result @Artur. I've updated the original question showing the current state of the code. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hi @DanielRodriguezMolina I've just made an ease example how you can access to `DS.ManyArray` http://jsfiddle.net/Mwg89/4/

Comment: Excelent @ArturMalecki! I've been trying your solution and it works perfect! Thank you so much, you saved my week! Just a small detail... Don't you think would be good to put `friends: function{...}.property('model.friends')` at the end of the property? To update the results in case of `friends` change. And again, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. You are right with `function{...}.property('model.friends')`. I've just updated my exampel and I added second way to access to `hasMany` relation.

Comment: the fiddle does not seem to generate any output. can you check it @ArturMałecki and post an update?